# Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync cannot create inIframe dialog

Tags: office-js

```
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(
        url,
        {
          height: 50,
          width: 50,
          displayInIframe: true, 
        },
)
```

set displayInframe to true, the dialog should be displayed as a floating overlay with an IFrame, but it still created a new browser window.

Platform: Excel 2016 on Mac

Answer (score 2):

The displayInIframe setting, as the [documentation](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/officeui.displaydialogasync) states, is only applicable for the Online (Web) platform. All other platforms (Windows, IOS, Mac) will display the dialog as a Pop-up inside the Office application (its not a stand alone browser window)

Comment: my problem was it did not display the dialog as pop up, rather, it create a standalone browser window on Mac :(
things becomes more weird today. For Excel Mac it works as expected, i.e. always create a pop up, which is awesome. However, for Excel Online, it is totally busted, throw 'An internal error has occurred'  exception.

Comment: I figured out why it create a new browser window, it opened a page in a different domain.